# MVVM Cross Unit testing possible with MSTest in Xamarin

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, mvvm, mvvmcross, mstest

Is it possible to do unit testing of Xamarin MVVM Cross View Models which are placed in pcl project with Microsoft Unit Testing Framework (MS-TEST)?

Comment: Yes I believe you can. Provided it targets the appropriate platform to be referenced by the test project

Comment: But while adding the test project dll it need n-unit dependencies. is this dll effectively works with mutest.

Comment: What are you referring to? you add the pcl to the test project not the other way around

Comment: Yes, I am doing same for my business logic in PCL but How can I create a mock up data Commands for ViewModel?

Comment: you need to provide a [mcve] of what it is you are referring to. Not much help can be provided otherwise. Show am example of the what it is you are trying to test and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok Sure, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. We provide a very basic Test NuGet which helps you set up the IoC container initially, which you may find useful. However, this package currently depends on NUnit, which it actually should not do as no code inside it depends on it.

Instead you can just yank the code from here and modify as suited: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Test/Test.Core/MvxIoCSupportingTest.cs

I will log a GitHub issue to fix the wrong dependency.

But there are not limitations on what Unit Test framework you use for your tests.